# Background image is not showing in chrome

Tags: html, css

so background image is not showing in chrome, but it's showing on all other browsers. I got background image and background color, but neather color nor image is showing up in chrome. It show's up perfectly on all other browsers, what could be the problem?

You can see the website here [Here](http://buenavistabistro.drivenmodels.net/)

Comment: Can you show us some code? May be create a fiddle too.

Comment: And please, change you display name to something proper. Help us, Help You :)

Comment: This question is completely useless without a code example. You cannot *seriously* expect us to guess how your code looks and come up with a proper solution...(?)

Comment: This isn't a coding question I believe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ Could be your problem if this is the intended image, Error: nothing found: 
[Link](http://buenavistabistro.drivenmodels.net/images/main-body-bg.jpg)

2/ Well this is interesting;

In Chrome right click, go to 'Inspect element' (very useful tool btw) you will see this:

```
<body class="home page page-id-2 page-template page-template-template-homepage-style2-
php top" style="background: none; background-image: 
url('http://buenavistabistro.drivenmodels.net/wp-content/themes/bordeaux/images/homepage-bg.JPG'); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-color: #0056C5;">
```

'http://buenavistabistro.drivenmodels.net/wp-content/themes/bordeaux/images/homepage-bg.JPG' is currently the background image for the homepage and it is just a tall thin plain white box

Comment: Please remove the full link from the text. About problem, any other suggestions?

Comment: That image is in the css which is publicly accessible anyway or is it just you don't want it advertised? I'm sorry I was asking why you said 'Nope it didn't solve the problem' - What didn't solve the problem?

Comment: Hello, I don't want it advertised. About solving the problem - I fixed the link, but it show's up the same.

Comment: Not sure what the difference between this and a full text link is but it changed. Answer also updated to help answer your question.

Comment: Mark it as the answer if it provided the answer to your problem please

Comment: I mean, with the picture everything is correct, i ment to do it so, the picture is 500px in height, and it should stop after 500px, and blue background should start.

Comment: Fixed it, by adding many background colors... probably not the bost solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where my background image was written properly in the CSS code but didn't display.

I found out that `text-indent` was set too extreme.

I had `text-indent: -999999999px;` or something mad.

I changed it to `text-indent: -99999px;` and now the background image displays properly.

Hope that helps someone.